# Find friend that has the highest number of common friends.. and returning his/her friends that are not in your list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find most connected friend's friend node with help of a Cypher query.

In the example below, given B, I need a query to return the "Salad" node but not the "Bacon" node. For this particular case, I have picked up node C (as opposed to node A), as the most connected friend. This is because B&C share most friends. Then I have picked up the friend of C that are not B's friend's list so that friend node (salad) can be recommended.

[image]

Given B, I need a Cypher query to return "Salad" node in Neo4j. Per Stefan's suggestion I have added Neo4j Console data [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=telae4). Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi Amy, please see edited question above. Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know the id of node B and C beforehand.

```
start b=node(<id_of_b>), c=node(<id_of_c>)
match c-[:LIKES]->stuff
where not(b-[:LIKES]->stuff)
return stuff
```

This should give you a list of items that C likes not B not, aka the "salad" node.

For future questions please consider setting up your data set on http://console.neo4j.org, this makes your question much clearer.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for taking time to reply. Actually I don't know the id of Node C. I am trying to create a recommendation for B based on the eating habits IF I know what they eat. So part of the challenge will be to find ID of C.

Comment: you're referring C being the "most connected fried" of b. Therefore you need a chained query that first finds b and then runs the query above. You can chain queries using `with`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I think I got it. Here is my final query. http://console.neo4j.org/r/6q17nq See if you approve.

Comment: Final answer based on Stefan's suggestion. start b=node:node_auto_index(name='B') 
Match p = b-[:LIKES]->stuff, someone_else_too -[:LIKES]->stuff 
with b, someone_else_too, count(p) as like_count 
order by count(p) desc 
limit 1 
match someone_else_too-[:LIKES]->stuff 
where not(b-[:LIKES]->stuff) 
return stuff